# Changing a POCO class name without causing a huge migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Here's an example of an entity we have inherited:

```
[Table("Vehicles")]
public partial class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Make Make { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Model Model { get; set; }
}
```

We want to refactor our code to rename this table "Vehicle". We can change the `[Table]` attribute to generate a migration file that does a `RenameTable(name: "dbo.Cars", newName: "Vehicles")`, all well and good.

However, if we try to change the class name, the migration scaffolder tries to create and THEN delete the same table. Here's a example:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Vehicles", "Make_Id", "dbo.Makes");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Vehicles", "Model_Id", "dbo.Models");
    DropIndex("dbo.Vehicles", new[] { "Make_Id" });
    DropIndex("dbo.Vehicles", new[] { "Model_Id" });
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Vehicles",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Make_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                Model_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Makes", t => t.Make_Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Models", t => t.Model_Id)
        .Index(t => t.Make_Id)
        .Index(t => t.Model_Id);

    DropTable("dbo.Vehicles");
}
```

Is there any way of making a change to the class name in code only (keeping the `[Table]` attribute the same), without causing this kind of behaviour? Or is this simply something I shouldn't be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use the migration as it is being generated. It tries to understand what you changed and create the migration that fits your work, but apparently the algorithm is confused in this case.

You can just alter the migration to execute the `RenameTable` method. This should work.

Neverless, please submit a bug report to the EF team at http://entityframework.codeplex.com